# Converting JSON Object to string replaces all / to \/

Tags: android, regex, json

I am converting JSON object to string to send it to server. But after conversion all `/` is changed to `\/`. I know this is the default behaviour of JSON. But after converting to string I am trying to replace `\/` to `/` by using string `replaceall()` method. But I think i am mistaking in the regular expression parameter in this method. I am using -

```
param = param.replaceAll("\"\"\"/", "/");
```

It's not working. Can anyone tell me the regex for `\/`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `param = param.replaceAll("\\/", "/");`

Comment: "I am converting JSON object to string" Using what code/library?

Comment: Just I feel I've seen different behaviours from different libraries.

Comment: is there are way to control the behavior of the escape characters being added to the final String while converting JSON object to string ?

Answer (score 0):

The regex `\/` matches a `/` character (char code 47).

You can check your regex easily with this awesome tool.

http://www.regexr.com/

Just paste your string and apply the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape control symbol "\" with escape sequence "\":

In general, try param = param.replaceAll("\/", "/")